# Azure - Sharing Azure services across different Azure Resource Group

Tags: azure

Can we share the Azure services created in one Azure resource group with other Azure resource group.

**For example:**

Resource Group 1 :  Has the below services

```
   - ServicesBus1
   - LogicApp1
   - RedisCache1
   - Keyvault1
```

I want to use the above services created in Resource Group 2 and Resource Group 3 services.

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem in using an Azure Service from one Resource Group in another. Resource Groups do not separate resources, they're just a grouping.

> A container that holds related resources for an Azure solution. The resource group can include all the resources for the solution, or only those resources that you want to manage as a group. You decide how you want to allocate resources to resource groups based on what makes the most sense for your organization.

The text below was taken from [What is an Azure resource group?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/cloud-adoption-guide/adoption-intro/resource-group-explainer)

> A resource group is simply an identifier that Azure Resource Manager applies to resources to group them together. This resource group ID allows Azure Resource Manager to perform operations on a group of resources that share this ID.
>
> A resource group cannot include resources from different subscriptions

And last but not least, take a look at this [Resource Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-overview#resource-groups) explanation. Especially look at item 1 in the list:

> All the resources in your group should share the same lifecycle. You deploy, update, and delete them together. **If one resource, such as a database server, needs to exist on a different deployment cycle it should be in another resource group**.

Answer (score 0):

A resource group is just a logical grouping of resources, it doesn't prevent services to use only resources within one resource group.

However, a resource can only belong to a single resource group. There is a **one-to-many** relationship between a resource group and a resource. A recource group can have multiple resources but each resource can only **belong to a single resource group**.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/cloud-adoption-guide/adoption-intro/resource-group-explainer)

Comment: You're right that a resource can only _belong_ to one resource group. I think OP is asking if he can _use_ a resource in resource group 1 from one in Resource Group 2, which _is_ possible.

Comment: @rickvdbosch You're right. I edited my answer - thank you!

Comment: Thank you for your help rickvdbosch and martin-brandl